# Seaborn FacetGrid error

Tags: python, seaborn

Inspired by examples on [this page](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html), I would like to make a seaborn facetgrid with the Iris dataset with 6 facets: 3 species x 2 types (petal or sepal). In each facet I need a histogram of length (or width).

But the code I tried gives a `ValueError: color kwarg must have one color per dataset`.

Any suggestions how to solve this?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as ply
import seaborn as sns
iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')
iris_petal = pd.DataFrame(iris.iloc[:,-3:].values, columns=['length', 'width', 'species'])
iris_petal['type'] = 'petal'
iris_sepal = pd.DataFrame(iris.iloc[:,[0, 1, -1]].values, columns=['length', 'width', 'species'])
iris_sepal['type'] = 'sepal'
iris = pd.concat([iris_sepal, iris_petal])
iris.sample(n=10)
g = sns.FacetGrid(iris, col="species",  row="type")
g = g.map(plt.hist, "length", color = 'b')
```

Comment: The strange thing is that this error even happens if you leave out `color = 'b'` from the code (with that line in, the error makes sense, right?).

Comment: The problem is that the data type of the numeric columns is `object`. I don't know why that is, but if you fix that it should work.

Comment: Thanks,  I didn't notice that, but it solves the issue! Can could you write that answer so I can mark it as correct?

Comment: Feel free to provide your own answer. I don't really have time right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@ImportanceOfBeingErnest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4124317/importanceofbeingernest) mentioned, it was a datatype issue.